# Expanding variables before saving Invoke-WebRequest results

Tags: powershell, invoke-webrequest

I am trying to write a simple program to log worklists from project cases which are normally displayed on an internal company website platform.

When I render the website for the project case in any browser and inspect the HTML, I see this:

```
<b style="margin-right: 0.3rem;">Worklist:</b> TEAM A
```

But when I run this command in Powershell:

```
Invoke-WebRequest http://www.example.com/projectXYZ -OutFile content.txt -UseDefaultCredentials
```

I get this instead:

```
<b style="margin-right:0.3rem">Worklist:</b>{{worklistAssignment}}
```

The HTML output also contains a number of variables that are listed near the end but not yet evaluated to their final displayed form, including this:

```
"worklistAssignment": null,
```

Is there a way that I can use `Invoke-WebRequest` to render a website fully, including resolving dynamic variables like `worklistAssignment` before saving the results?

Clearly there is some processing of these null variables during webpage rendering. I want the values of those variables supplied by the backend as the webpage is normally rendered to be output in my text file.